# Selenium Webdriver Timeout exception handling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've traditionally seen timeout handling like this:

```
from socket import timeout

try:
#something
except timeout:
#something else
```

I am having web driver timeout exceptions however I can't seem to figure out what they are called. In my trace statements I'm seeing TimeoutException... But when I say except TimeoutException it cannot be found.

How do I handle these?

I googled but did not find an exception that worked.

Comment: Can you share the actual code you're using to catch the exception, and the traceback you're getting?

Comment: `from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException` You need to handle this exception

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich of great thank you I was looking in web driver

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi, I'm wondering why do you want to handle TimeoutException in webdriver test at all? Could you describe a case please?